# Ruby on Rails stylesheet rendering files and application.css with common css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stylesheet

I'm wondering what `application.css` is for? If I'm creating a new file for `header` and `footer` so all my pages can just include `header` and `footer` page, do I just put all common css syntax in `application.css`? or should I just create a new `custom.css` and place all the syntax that is going to be used throughout my application like body, html, ul, a, tags and stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is `application.css` for? Have you read the Rails guide on the **[Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)**? That page alone answers your "what's it for?" question and more very clearly and thoroughly.

As for placement of your styling, the guide mentions:

> The default matcher for compiling files includes application.js, application.css and all non-JS/CSS files (i.e., .coffee and .scss files are not automatically included as they compile to JS/CSS):

This means by default Rails is only going to compile an `application.css` file for you. Sure, you can put your styling in `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css` and include it with

```
/**
 *= require custom 
 */
```

but your "custom" styling sounds like application styling, so it seems it'd be best to just drop it all into `application.css` and let Rails do what it does by default.